# Post Custom & Taxonomy 404 error

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, links

Basically the single Permanent link are giving me 404 errors.

might be wrong?

Code is below:

```
function post_types(){
register_post_type('carta',array(
    'labels'            => array(
        'name'              => 'Cartas',
        'singular_name'     => 'Carta',
        'all_items'         => 'Todos la Carta',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Añadir nueva Item a la Carta',
        'edit_item'         => 'Editar Carta',
        'search_items'      => 'Buscar Carta',
        'not_found'         => 'No se encontro Ningún item de la Carta.',
        'not_found_in_trash'=> 'Ningún item de la carta encontrado en la papelera.',
         'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'carta', 'with_front' => false),
    ),

    'public'            => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-slides',
    'supports'          => array('title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes','common'),
));
}
add_action('init','post_types');
```

Taxonomy

```
function create_taxonomies() {
register_taxonomy('category', array('carta'), array(
    'labels' => array(
     'name' => 'Categorias'
    ),
    'hierarchical' => TRUE,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => false,
));

}
add_action('init', 'create_taxonomies');
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings/permalinks and click save.

To prevent this from being a problem with plugins, or themes that insatiate CPT's/ Taxonomies there is the function `flush_rewrite_rules`. [here is the link from the codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules)

Comment: If it hss been answered a million times, flag the question as duplicate to one of those million ;-)

Comment: Point taken. I guess you are after me!?

Comment: I can see how my original answer can be perceived as rude and elitist. I apologize.